# Change the name of the table according the changes in while loop

Tags: mysql, php

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT topics FROM subjects";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    for($x = 1; $x <= 4; $x++)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo '<li>';
        echo $row["topics"];

        $display = "SELECT content FROM '$row["topics"]'  " ;
        $run = mysqli_query($db, $display);
        echo $run ;
        $dis = "SELECT LEFT(content, 40) FROM '$row["topics"]';
        $run1 = mysqli_query($db, $dis);
        echo $run1;

        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

I have different subject names like `English` `Math` `science` `history` and I want to display it in a `ul` and want to display 40 characters.
When the user clicks a new page, it should redirect it to new page where he can see the full content.
How do i accomplish that?

Comment: can you give a glimpse of your expected output? it will be easy then to give you solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors in the queries. No need of `'`s.  The queries should be -

```
$display = "SELECT content FROM " .$row["topics"] ;

$dis = "SELECT LEFT(content, 40) FROM " . $row["topics"];
```